# Vue.js offcanvas content

Tags: html, vuejs2

I am working on this website using vue.js. it uses google maps api. I put there an offcanvas sidebar that opens and closes on click. I'm trying to put stuff into my sidebar but it doesn't work and always show me undefined.

P.S. I'm new to vue and the version I'm using is 2 and it uses ES5, NOT ES6.

Here's the js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// noinspection JSAnnotator
var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#map-control',

    // data: {
    //     title:'HELLO WORLD'
    // },
    mounted: function () {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.6062, -122.3321);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: latLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,

            // disables the yellow man
            panControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            // disables other types of MAP, forces to only use Satellite view
            mapTypeControlOptions: {mapTypeIds: []}
        };
        // add the map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        map.setOptions({minZoom: 3, maxZoom: 15});

    },
    components: {
        'vue-offcanvas': VueOffcanvas
    },

    data: function data() {
            return {
                showDefault: false,
                align: 'left'
            }

    },

    methods: {
        show: function show(align) {
            this.align = align;
            this.showDefault = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the HTML file:

```
<div id="map-control">
    <div id="site-canvas">

        <div class="site-menu">
            <button class ="navbar-header btn btn-md btn-secondary" type="button" @click="show('left')">&#9776;</button>
        </div>

        <vue-offcanvas v-model="showDefault" :align="align" :width="600" :duration=".3" effect="ease-in-out" class="site-menu">
            Sidebar Content goes here
            <div class="site-menu">

                <button class="navbar-header btn btn-md btn-secondary" type="button" @click="showDefault = false">

                </button>
            </div>

        </vue-offcanvas>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, you are having `jQuery` and `Vue` at the same time. Maybe in the future you can look for a Vue component for Google map over `npm`.

For now, you have local variable messed up inside `mounted`. Whatever local inside is not gonna work outside that function, including templates. This might work if you declare it a variable for the component like `title`,

```

```
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#map-control',

  data: function data() {
    return {
      map: null
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(...);
  }
});
```

```